# Filtering a json array obtained from a web service to only contain certain elements - Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http-get, angular-filters

I am creating a project which uses a HTTP get from a web service and returns an array of projects, with ID, name, description etc.

There is many projects within this web service but I am only concerned with 9 of them the rest are irrelevant.

I have a desired set of 9 projects with unique ID's declared in the project.service.http.ts class that I want to only be showing.

I am trying to filter the HTTP get request to only include the 9 specific Ids, which I store in a projectIds array of type string.

**EDIT2:**
With logging the response:
[image]

EDIT SOLVED:
I changed the constructor in the project.viewer.component from :

```
 constructor(private service: ProjectService) {
        this.service.fetchProjects().subscribe(response => {
          this.projects = response.filter(elements => {
            // BaseComponent was my class. Use yours.
            return ProjectViewerComponent.projectIds.includes(elements.id);
          });
        })
      }
```

to :

```
 constructor(private service: ProjectService) {
        this.service.fetchProjects().subscribe(response => {
          this.projects = response['project'].filter(elements => {
            // BaseComponent was my class. Use yours.
            return ProjectViewerComponent.projectIds.includes(elements.id);
          });
        })
      }
```

The Key was the ['project'] after the this.projects = response

project.service.http.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectServiceHttp extends ProjectService {

    //variables
    baseUrl = "http://...";

        static projectIds: string[] = ["..."
                                ,"...", "..","..."];

        //constructor
       constructor(private http: Http) {
            super();
        }

    //methods
    fetchProjects(): Observable<any>{
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options)
          .map((response: Response) => response.json())
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }

        private handleError(error: any) {
            // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
            // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
            let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
            console.log(errMsg); // log to console instead
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
        }
}
```

project.viewer.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'project-viewer',
    templateUrl: './project-viewer.html',  
    styleUrls: ['./project-viewer.css']
})


export class ProjectViewerComponent  {
    name = 'ProjectViewerComponent';
    projects: Project[] = [];

    static testIds: string[] = ['qqq', 'aaa'];

    static projectIds: string[] = ["...","..."
    ,"..","..","...","..."
    ,"..", "...","..."];

    errorMessage = "";
    stateValid = true;

      constructor(private service: ProjectService) {
        this.service.fetchProjects().subscribe(response => {
          this.projects = response.filter(elements => {
            return ProjectViewerComponent.projectIds.includes(elements.id);
          });
        })
      }

    private raiseError(text: string): void {
        this.stateValid = false;
        this.errorMessage = text;
    }
}
```

project-viewer.html:

```
<h3>Projects </h3>
<div >
    <ul class= "grid grid-pad">
        <a *ngFor="let project of projects" class="col-1-4">
            <li class ="module project" >
                <h4 tabindex ="0">{{project.name}}</h4>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: replace your map selector with just `return response.json();` try. Also if u get error. please attach the image of both the request expanded response in the **developer conole, network tab** and the full error shown in the console ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `fetchProjects()` from your service could be re-used in another component. So you might want it to return all the projects, since it's the aim of this method. To fetch all the projects.

**First method (recommended) :**

The best thing would be to filter the data you get from the return of your HTTP Call.

In that way, you need to filter the data you get from the service to display only what you want in that component.

**project.viewer.component.ts :**

```
.subscribe(response =>{
  this.projects = response.project.
    .filter(elements => someCondition);
  console.log(response);
  console.log(this.projects);
},
```

**Second method (not recommended) :**

The only time you will want to use the `.map()` method to change the data you get from your service call is when you are sure you won't ever need to have all the projects, but only these ones. Of course, you could do another function that would call the same URL and not filter that data, but then you will have to maintain two methods doing basically the same call. That's why it's better to filter your data in your component and not in your service.

Nonetheless, you would need to change this part in your service :

**project.service.http.ts :** (should be called **project.service.ts** btw)

```
.map((response: Response) => {
  const results = response.json();
  return = results.filter(elements => someCondition);
})
```

---

**EDIT :** Here is the working solution with your class object and my own mock data :

**project.service.http.ts** : **Initial one, don't use `.filter()`**.

```
fetchProjects(): Observable<any>{
  const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**project.viewer.component.ts :**

You will need to adapt a bit since I took some of your code to do a fast example (my projects IDs are `'qqq'` and `'aaa'`).

```
  static projectIds: string[] = ['yourIds', 'YourIds2', ...];

  projects: Project[] = [];

  constructor(private service: ProjectService) {
    this.service.fetchProjects().subscribe(response => {
      this.projects = response.filter(element => BaseComponent.projectIds.includes(element.id)); // BaseComponent was my class. Use yours.
    })
  }
```

**project-viewer.html :** **Unchanged.**

In my example, my service sends me 4 projects, and I filter 2 of them to only display 2. Works great, tell me if you have any problem adapting to your code.

As you can see, this is the application of the first method I mentionned first. Do not apply this to the service as well for the reasons stated in the second method.

Comment: so for the filter part, if I declare an array of strings (projectIds) in my project.service.http.ts class with the ones I want to return - how can I refer to them?

Comment: That's up to you but that's the idea yeah. The best thing would be to filter on   either the projects IDs or Names, but you need to add data to your projects to know which ones you want programatically. What do these 9 projects have that the others don't ? You could add an extra property which would be returned by your service as well (like a boolean : `isMainProject` and the others wouldn't have it). This way you could do : `.filter(elements => elements.isMainProject);` The only other solution would be to create a static array of your wanted name projects. And use `Array.includes()`

Comment: There is many projects within this web service but I am only concerned with 9 of them the rest are irrelevant. I cant edit the projects on the server side so I cant add a boolean to them etc. 

If i use a static array like I have mentioned above with 9 specific IDs, using .filter can I specifically say this for example: 
.filter(elements => elements.includes(projectIds)?

Comment: what do you think of the solution above (by amal) for this situation?

Comment: I don't think it's very good since pipes should be used for reusability, and since this is a very specific use-case, this pipe would not have any other usability. Besides, it uses the same `filter()` method, so the result (and your problematic) would be the same. See this article : https://codeburst.io/angular-bad-practices-eab0e594ce92 (Not using/Misusing Pipes)

Comment: I'd use `Array.filter` too - using a pipe for this is definitely not the right approach.

Comment: Well, I initially recommended this approach thinking that OP needed the rest of his response elements for other purposes (He later clarified further on his requirements after I posted my answer). Using a pipe would simply restrict its (the response's) output on a template and he can keep using the same object elsewhere. If he don't care about the remaining response data, then of course he could use direct filtering while retrieving the response.

Comment: @Alex Beugnet I have updated my code but using the same filtering it wont produce any projects when running..

Comment: if I am unable to achieve it the first way(direct filtering) them I will happily use the pipe approach. just as long as the desired 9 are output. having a bit of bother trying to use the direct filtering method (updated code above)

Comment: That's because your `filter()` is not working correctly, and since no result passes the condition, you end up with no project at all since everything has been filtered out. I'll make a little example and provide the correct syntax to your issue in an edit

Comment: @AlexBeugnet could be rite. The filter in the service is being evaluated on a undefined/non-existing property and hence the observable flow breaks.

Comment: Edited with provided working solution. (What a ton of work for a simple `filter()` :-) )

Comment: @amal Even if he only needs part of the object, he could store it in a private property in his component before filtering it, and even if he needed the data in another component, I'd either `share()` the result of the HTTP call to the different components, or use the service as a store to send the data to several components. The pipe would still be used for a one time operation, which is cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: @Alex Beugnet instead of creating an observable of fake data, how do I use that so I can use my http get from web service as the observable?

so when mapping, let result = response.json(), then             return Observable.of(result);
??

this doesnt work: error: ERROR TypeError: response.filter is not a function

Comment: You don't need to change anything, it was just my way of faking it to be able to subscribe to the result. Revert to your original service

Comment: Edited with original service

Comment: @Alex Beugnet it doesnt work i tried to implement already thats why i posted another question. I get this in console: ERROR TypeError: response.filter is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next (project.viewer.component.ts:53)
........
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad

Comment: can you edit your original post with my working solution to know where the error comes from ? It's working in my own example, so it's only a minor issue now

Comment: @AlexBeugnet Edited the post

Comment: Can you provide a `console.log()` of `response.json()` in your service ?

Comment: @Alex Beugnet How do I manipulate the fetchProjects method to log the response in the console? gives me unreachable code

Comment: The syntax `() => result` is a sugar-syntax for simple functions : It's basically : `() : function() { return result };` You need to add the brackets and add the return to be able to add a `console.log()`.

Basically : `.map((response: Response) => { console.log(response.json()); return response.json(); })`

Comment: @Alex Beugnet Included the console.log screenshot of the response.json() .. solved it by changing the constructor in the component. It now displays the filtered 9 projects. Edited post above to show what solved it finally!Thanks for your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `pipe` to filter those projects based on your condition (that passes only for those 'unique ids') and apply them on your `*ngFor` in the template like this,

```
<a *ngFor="let project of projects | uniqueOnes" class="col-1-4">
```

Define the pipe like this,

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'uniqueOnes'
})
export class UniqueOnesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  uniqueIds = [ 'id1', 'id2', 'id5'];

  transform(value: any): any {
    return value
            ? value.filter(project => { return <condition to pass only the unique projects (For ex: this.uniqueIds.indexOf(project.id) !== -1)>  })
            : value;
  }

}
```

More on pipes [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pipes).

Comment: tried to implement this but got : Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'uniqueOnes' could not be found ("

Comment: Updated my answer. See if that makes sense. I used `this` to refer to the class's property.

Comment: By the way, were you able to get it working with this approach?

Comment: yes @amal it worked, although implementing the array rather than the actual values in the filter didn't work the first time, only when specifying all 9 like this :   ? value.filter(project => { return  ['TotalMobileAnalyseInsights', 'TotalMobileMendel','TotalMobileSlam','TotalMobileServer','TotalMobileWedAdmin','TotalMobileForAndroid'
              ,'TotalMobileForWindows','TotalMobileForWindowsUniversal','TotalMobileForIOS'].indexOf(project.id) !== -1})
              : value;

Comment: Just use the `filter()` method you used in the example I posted in my answer, it should work the same way

Comment: @Liam sorry I didn't get what you mean by 'first time' ? You mean it was working in one way and not in another way? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @amal, i meant it didnt work with the array rather than the actual values in the filter. I didnt pursue it after that because of the other responses saying there was a more suitable way.

Comment: No offense, but he is lost... He just tried to use my mock data as a real service... I even stated that he should use his original service method without .filter() in it... 
So the new question makes no sense

Comment: @AlexBeugnet your solution doesnt work. Because in the project.service.ts, the fetchProjects method, the response returned is not an array - so it cant use the .filter method associated with it. so this line in the viewer component: this.projects = response.filter(elements => { does not work. which is why I am asking the question again clearly - so I can solve it.

Comment: Oh, what does it return then ? I assumed it was an array of Projects, but it returns an `Obersable<any>` so I can't know what kind of return it is.
**EDIT :** In your screenshot, we can see on the right that it returns an Array of Projects...

Comment: @Liam, the way you have mocked your 'projects' also shows they are an array. We both assumed it to be an array to begin with. It should be, otherwise it wouldn't have worked for you using the pipes I proposed earlier.